# Cannot find my Déjà Dup Backup Tool

Tags: backup, deja-dup

hi I am trying to back my home directory up and I know that I have Déjà Dup Backup Tool installed but for  some reason I cannot get to find it in order to back my files up. I don't want to remove it and reinstall it, as I have previous back up on it. I Think it would have been easier if one could start an application from the installed tab of the software centre as the only option it give is to remove it. Maybe there is a way that I might not be aware of .
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `whereis deja-dup` ?
By the way removing Déjà Dup shouldn't erase your backups as they are stored where you told Déjà Dup to store them.